# Read files within maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to create a maven-plugin that generates new files based on a template file (basically using the FreeMarker language). I can successfully generate the files if I run the maven plugin from the directory of my maven-plugin project since my plugin accesses the template file based on a relative path.

However, if I try to run the plugin in some other java project directory, I cannot find the template file. I do not want to copy the templated file into the new java project.

I searched around to see if the maven plugin can access files within itself when another project is using the plugin but wasn't successful. Most of the documentation refers to accessing the java project files, and not the maven-plugin files.

Is this even possible or is there a better approach/workaround to tackle the problem?

Edit (Directory structure):

```
Maven-Plugin (FileGenerator):
src
--main
  --java
     --FileGenerator.java (references the TemplateFile based on the path to the root project)
TemplateFile
```

If I run the plugin as a standalone, I am able to generate new files based on the TemplateFile. I achieve the following structure

```
Maven-Plugin (FileGenerator):
src
--main
  --java
     --FileGenerator.java 
TemplateFile
NewFile1
NewFile2
```

However, if I run the plugin in another directory (such as part of another java project) with the command `mvn myplugin:mypluginplugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:build`

```
Another Java Project
src
--main
  --java
    --AnotherFile.java
pom.xml
```

I get an error mentioning that the TemplateFile cannot be found. Is there a way for the plugin to reference the TemplateFile regardless of where it is run at?

Ideal Output After running plugin

```
Another Java Project
src
--main
  --java
    --AnotherFile.java
pom.xml
NewFile1
NewFile2
```

Comment: Maybe you can enhance this one: https://github.com/mojohaus/templating-maven-plugin. Apart from that you can read the files through the classpath or just using to read them via `getResourceAsStream()` ? Or what is the real problem here?

Comment: The problem is that I use a template file that is located in my maven plugin repository and generate new files based on it. My maven plugin needs to know the path to the template file in order to create new files. However, since I am planning on using the plugin as part of another java project, I can't seem to create the new files because the directory to the template changed. Is there a way to have the maven plugin always reference the template based on its own directory structure, regardless of wherever it is running?

Comment: Can you make an example layout of the directories and explain it a little bit more...

Comment: I edited the question to add the directory structure. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: The first question which comes across my mind is: Should that template file being part of the maven-plugin or should be part of the project in which you run your plugin?

Comment: I really want it to be part of the plugin. I understand that if the template file was part of the project, there would be no problem and I could easily reference the project directory properties to generate the new files.

Comment: Ok..than you need to put the template files into `src/main/resources` directory to get packaged into the resulting plugin jar file...and get the resources in your plugin code via `getClass().getResourceAsStream('/templateFile.xxx')` ?

Comment: One more thing is. After you have created files you should never generate something in the src directory or in the root directory of your project. You should generate files in `target/generated-sources/XXXX` (you should decide a name for XXXX`)...

Comment: I was able to get it working. Thank you for everything. I really appreciate the time you spent answering my questions. Thanks.